# Why don't we use an article in this sentence?

Tags: articles

> A: What kind of puppies do you have?
> B: We have healthy and funny puppies.

Why don't we use "the healthy and funny puppies" since we are already talking about known puppies to us.

Comment: We don't use the definite article when we use an adjective with something already mentioned. The answer might have been "The puppies in that cage are poodles, and the ones over there are terriers."

Comment: Oh, so we dont use the definite article when we use an adjective with something already mentioned at all? Like: "What colour flat do you have? I have a big flat."

Comment: That would be correct, except that _big_ isn't a colour!

Comment: Because the question isn't about specifying which puppies, but about which *kind of* puppies. The kind "healthy and funny puppies" hasn't been mentioned yet. Notice that even in the question, you don't say, "*What kind of **the** puppies do you have?*" even though in the context someone has obviously mentioned the puppies before.

Comment: In English, don't with an apostrophe.